# If statements within a Query

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, import, google-query-language

I'm using a query & importrange combo like this:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EizWsVwZfUy1NDRwmmWEpj2OxTGvBjP9-YBbds9xmr0/edit#gid=0", "'Locations'!A2:C"), "select Col3 where Col1='"&J4&"' and Col1<>''"))
```

But Instead of just searching column 1 and returning the associated value in column 3, I would like it to return the associated value in: 
Col3 if the value is in Col1 
Col7 if the value is in Col5 
Col11 if the value is in Col9

It can throw an error if the value is in more than one place, or return the result at the first occurrence, either way is fine.

I'm trying to do this using "countif" within the query but am not having a much luck.

Comment: Please share a sample sheet with sample data to test, where we can properly replicate your setup & provide a good solution to your problem. See [Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I agree with @IrvinJayG. Your current formula is written to bring in 3 columns, but you seem to want to reference 11 columns. It's unclear if those columns are within your source sheet or destination sheet. And, on top of that, keep in mind that we can't see your spreadsheet, so we don't know your layout, data, data types, international locale settings and a lot more that would be necessary in order to answer such a question.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY({
 IMPORTRANGE("1EizWsVwZfUy1NDRwmmWEpj2OxTGvBjP9-YBbds9xmr0", "Locations!A2:C");
 IMPORTRANGE("1EizWsVwZfUy1NDRwmmWEpj2OxTGvBjP9-YBbds9xmr0", "Locations!E2:G");
 IMPORTRANGE("1EizWsVwZfUy1NDRwmmWEpj2OxTGvBjP9-YBbds9xmr0", "Locations!I2:K")}, 
 "select Col3 where Col1='"&J4&"' and Col1 is not null", ))
```